# What is the plural of "hell of a *"?

Tags: idioms

I can't find any reference to a plural form of "hell of a *".
Some say this does not exist because "hell of A " means "A remarkable x among all x"
But what if the noun is commonly used  at plural (glasses, trousers...).
What will be the correct form then?

- Apple glasses would be one hell of a glasses?
- Apple glasses would be one hell of glasses?

Comment: Glasses and trousers are still "one thing". We don't say, for example, "That elephant is one hell of an elephant" with the repetition, but either "That is one hell of an elephant" or "That elephant is one hell of a thing." For glasses and trousers, it would be too clumsy trying to put the subject last.

Comment: I think your question is based on a slight misinterpretation.  We never use it in the plural, because the meaning of "X is a hell of a thing" is really more like "the **existence of** X is a hell of a thing."  So the phrase would just be like "apple glasses would be one hell of a thing."

Comment: @Weather Vane. So, there's no such thing as : great apes are one hell of animals?

Comment: We'd say, "A great ape is one hell of an animal" - theoretically, that is.  I can't imagine anyone actually saying that.  This is a limitation of the cliché.  It only supports singular objects.  And it's use is probably even more strict than that, though it's hard to say exactly what the limits are.  For example, "A pair of Apple Glasses would be one hell of a pair of glasses" isn't incorrect, but it's unlikely to be heard.  Probably because it's too cumbersome.

Comment: No, we would not say "great apes are one hell of animals".

Comment: Hi @WeatherVane, is it correct to say **Apple glasses would be one hell of a new kind of glasses** (by grouping them into a single kind, I think it's possible to use the idiom but I'm not sure).

Comment: No, please see my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "hell of a *(something)*" only works in the singular form. When it comes to things like *glasses* or *trousers*, you have to make them singular in the same way you would if saying "one *(something)*." Specifically, you have one *pair* of glasses or of trousers. So:

> That's one hell of a pair of glasses.